# C++ CodeBlocks compile two source files

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, gtkmm

I have tried to compile those files by CodeBlocks which i have downloaded from here:

> https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm-documentation/tree/examples/book/frame?h=master

When i try to compile it with Code Blocks i get that error:

> main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()'|

But i compile it like that from terminal it works:

```
g++ main.cc examplewindow.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Is there any idea how to make Code Blocks compile two source files ?
[image]

> -------------- Build: Debug in youtube (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g  -std=gnu++11 -pthread
>   -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0      -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -c /home/bahaa/programming/c++/youtube/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o g++ 
>   -o bin/Debug/youtube obj/Debug/main.o   -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0      obj/Debug/main.o: In function `main': /home/bahaa/programming/c++/youtube/main.cpp:8: undefined
>   reference to`ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()'
>   /home/bahaa/programming/c++/youtube/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to
>   `ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()'
>   /home/bahaa/programming/c++/youtube/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to`
>   ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds) 3
>   errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v3koVNb7hU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Do you have it in a project? What's its layout? What command do you see in the build window? The answer is yes, but if you want to know why you didn't succeed you have to show what you tried.

Comment: I just added then in codeblocks and renamed them nothing else

Answer (score 0):

The command you put in your terminal looks completely different from the command codeblocks is executing, so the fact that it does something different is logic.
However in the case of a `undefined reference` it usually means that you are forgetting an `include` somewhere. Where is `ExampleWindow` declared/defined? Is it in included in your `main` through one of the two includes you are doing?